# Swift - UIControl addTarget not working

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicontrol

I have created XIB with `UIView`. I have assigned class `MyViewControl: UIControl` to it, so I can add touch up inside action. It works, touches are called inside my class.

Now, I have created `UICollectionView` and add this "xib" as cell view. I want now touches to be handled inside `UICollectionViewDelegate` class. So I have done this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    for v in cell.contentView.subviews {            
        if let c: MyViewControl = v as? MyViewControl {               
            c.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            c.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClick), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        }
    }        
}

func myClick(sender: Any){
    print("click....")
}
```

However, `myClick` selector is never called. If I add `UIButton` to the `MyViewControl` and do the same thing (`addTarget`) for this button, callbacks are correctly called.

Comment: just implement the method as `func myClick(){
    print("click....")
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add underscore `_` before sender in function as `_ sender: Any` and add `(_:)` in the `#selector` under `action` viz. `myClick(_ :)`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    for v in cell.contentView.subviews {            
        if let c: MyViewControl = v as? MyViewControl {               
            c.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            c.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClick(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        }
    }        
}

func myClick(_ sender: Any){
    print("click....")
}
```

Hope this helps